# magento 2 : How to render background images in phtml pages

Tags: magento2, phtml

How do you render a background image from a phtml page.

I have tried this:

```
<div class="home-slider--bg-slide" style="background-image: url('@{baseDir}images/home-slider/slide-1.jpg');"></div>
```

And this:

```
 <div class="home-slider--bg-slide" style="background-image: url(/images/home-slider/slide-1.jpg);"></div>
```

My images are held in my website theme:

```
\app\design\frontend\Mytheme\Theme-frontend-default\web\images
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use following code in your .phtml file to get your website theme path.

```
<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/home-slider/slide-1.jpg') ?>
```

So your code is like following, please check and let me know if you get any issue.

```
<div class="home-slider--bg-slide" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl("images/home-slider/slide-1.jpg") ?>');"></div>
```